# How to check if a form could be submited outside the component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using React Form Hook, and i'm doing a register page which is divided in steps with different forms, i want to check if the form was submited correctly before changing to the next step, but the submit is managed by React Hook Form in other component

I've tried to listen when the form was submited:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(steps && step){
      document.getElementById(steps[step].form).addEventListener('submit', () => {
         if (step !== 2) setStep(step + 1)
      })
   }}, [step, steps])
```

I also tried to create a submit button everytime we click the 'next' button, but it doesnt work neither

By the way, this is the 'next' button

```
<button type='submit' form={steps[step].form} className="hvr-i-right">
    {step !== 2 ? 'Next' : 'Finish'}
    <i className="material-icons hvr-i">arrow_forward</i>
</button>
```

Comment: can you pls add example so i can help more

Comment: https://ibb.co/fY0PtXR 
I want that you can't click the next before complete all information needed in the form